# Word that means weight? (heath?)

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm trying to spell the word that sounds like "heath" meaning weightiness?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Could you be thinking of **heft**?

Comment: You should mark responses that satisfy your queries as 'Answered'.